# Why MAX() of SUM() giving wrong output?

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I have a table employee

```
id    name   salary  city
1     ram    50000   c1
2     sham   20000   c2
3     jadu   80000   c1
4     madhu  90000   c4
5     hari   10000   c2
6     gopal  34000   c3
7     komal  55000   c3
8     bappa  98000   c4
```

query is which city earning the highest.
i tried

```
SELECT city, SUM(salary) AS maxSalary 
FROM employee GROUP BY city ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1;
```

it works fine but if there are more than one max earning cities then it doesn't output other max cities, only the first one.

so i tried this query

```
SELECT city, MAX(totalSalary) maxSalary 
FROM( SELECT city, SUM(salary) AS totalSalary FROM employee GROUP BY city  ) AS tempTable
```

it is giving

```
city  max
c1    188000
```

but correct is

```
city  max
c4    188000
```

It means it is outputting the first most city name of the table which is `c1` but not the correct max earning city name which is `c4`.
What is the right query?

Comment: Heere is something similar http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38e44/1, tested with identical sums for 2 cities.

Comment: @Mihai I think in your query it is better to use `=` instead of `IN` caluse cause `IN` is used if there are multiple values to choose from , but we need max only and the number of value will be one only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sent the wrong query to the database.
You hit a mysql extension that is described in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html). 
A query like

```
SELECT city, MAX(salary) 
from employee
```

will not work in standard SQL. It raises an error in [Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6c81/1) (error message: "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function") , in [MSSqlServer 2012](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6c81/1) (error message: "Column 'employee.city' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause")  or [postgresql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e6c81/1) (error message:"ERROR: column "employee.city" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function").

In standard SQL expressions in the select list can only be expressions of columns that are also used in the group by clause and of  aggregate functions. A column values  that is used in the group by clause is the same for all rows in these group. The aggregate is also unique for a group.
The select returns one row for each group containing this uniquely defined values for a group.

If the aggregate query does not have a group by clause ther is only one group of rows.

The standard does not allow to use an arbitrary column in the select list of an aggregate query because its value not uniquely defined: the column has different values for the rows of the query so which one should be returned for this group by the query?

In mysql there is the extension that if there is a column in an expression (not an in an aggregate function expression) that is not in the group by clause the value returned by the select statement for this group is the value of this column of an arbitrary row of this group.

So the query

```
SELECT city, MAX(salary) 
from employee
```

returns the sumof all employees' salaries and the city of one of these rows. But the query return exactly one reow becuase it is an aggregate query and there is only one group that contains all records from employee table.

The query

```
SELECT city, MAX(salary) 
from employee
group by city
```

returns a row for each city with the city and of the salaries of each city.

The query

```
SELECT city, salary
from employee
group by city
```

returns arow for each city with and salaty of an arbitrary employee of this city.  The server decides which employee of a city is choosen.

The query

```
SELECT city, zipcode
from employee
group by city
```

also return a row for each city with the zipcode of this city. If we assume that every city haas only one 
zipcode than the rows of each group defined by a city contain al the same zipcode. so independent of the row the server selects the retuned zicode wil always be the zipcode of the city.

In standard SQL this query would be written as

```
SELECT city, zipcode
from employee
group by city, zipcode
```

to create the expected result

`group by city,zipcode` and `group city` define the same groups because of the one to one correspondence between zipcdoe an city.

---

The query

```
SELECT city, SUM(salary) 
from employee
group by city
```

will contain not only  the needed rows but more.

A way to filter out the needed rows from this query is the following

```
SELECT city, SUM(salary) 
from employee
group by city 
having SUM(salary) >= all (select SUM(salary)  city_salary 
     from employee
     group by city)
```

There are other ways to filter.

The largest salary sum can be found by the following query

```
select MAX(city_salary)  
   from (select SUM(salary)  city_salary 
     from employee
     group by city) tab
```

(Note: In Oracle the same can be achieved by

```
select MAX(SUM(salary))  city_salary 
  from employee
  group by city
```

)

So we can use it to filter out the needed one:

```
SELECT city, SUM(salary) 
from employee
group by city 
having SUM(salary) = (select MAX(city_salary)  
   from (select SUM(salary)  city_salary 
     from employee
     group by city) tab)
```

This  solution was  already presented by @Mihai in his [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74752/why-max-of-sum-giving-wrong-output#comment-134882).

Comment: We are talking about max value/values of of SUM(), not just MAX().

Comment: Thank you, i require 15 reputations to upvote your answer or i would upvote.

Comment: your last query outputs just the sum of all cities' salary

Answer (score 4):

You are using `max()` an aggregate function over your `tempTable` result set without providing grouping criteria, when you use any aggregate function with out group by it will assume all rows as one group and will result in indeterminate order like the city your are will will be returned in indeterminate order ,`max()` will guarantee you the max value from result set but it not  guarantee the associated column value (in your case city is associated column) therefore you are getting city **c1** instead of **c4** .

However you have achieved you answer by using sub-queries which are not so efficient because a sub-query has to run for every row to match the value from the result set of `tempTable` so i suggest you to use cross join with a sub-select instead instead of sub-query in where use `HAVING` to match results of aggregate function

Sample Data

```
INSERT INTO employee
    (`id`, `name`, `salary`, `city`)
VALUES
    (1, 'ram', 50000, 'c1'),
    (2, 'sham', 20000, 'c2'),
    (3, 'jadu', 80000, 'c1'),
    (4, 'madhu', 90000, 'c4'),
    (5, 'hari', 10000, 'c2'),
    (6, 'gopal', 34000, 'c3'),
    (7, 'komal', 55000, 'c3'),
    (8, 'bappa', 98000, 'c4')
;
```

Query

```
SELECT 
e.city,
SUM(e.salary) AS totalSalary ,
e1.maxSalary
FROM employee e
CROSS JOIN (SELECT city, SUM(salary) AS maxSalary
            FROM employee
            GROUP BY city
            ORDER BY maxSalary
            DESC LIMIT 1
           ) e1
GROUP BY e.city
HAVING totalSalary = e1.maxSalary
```

Sample Result

```
CITY    TOTALSALARY MAXSALARY
c4       188000     188000
```

### [`Fiddle Demo 1`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d858/2)

Benefit of using cross join with sub-select is the sub-query in cross join will be evaluated 
only once as compare to sub-query in your answer ,in cross join's sub-select just get the max summed salary of employee by ordering in descending manner with limit 1 will give you the highest summed salary and with your query's sum result compare the maxsalary calculated by sub-select of cross join in having clause .

From fiddle demo 1 the max salary was 188000 so for your case if 2 employees has same max salary then return both of them so i have slightly modified sample data with one more row another employee with the same highest salary as `(9, 'test', 188000, 'c5')` as you can see the fiddle demo 2 is using same query to evaluate for returning both employees with same highest salary

Sample Data

```
INSERT INTO employee
    (`id`, `name`, `salary`, `city`)
VALUES
    (1, 'ram', 50000, 'c1'),
    (2, 'sham', 20000, 'c2'),
    (3, 'jadu', 80000, 'c1'),
    (4, 'madhu', 90000, 'c4'),
    (5, 'hari', 10000, 'c2'),
    (6, 'gopal', 34000, 'c3'),
    (7, 'komal', 55000, 'c3'),
    (8, 'bappa', 98000, 'c4'),
    (9, 'test', 188000, 'c5')
;
```

Sample Result set

```
CITY    TOTALSALARY MAXSALARY
c4      188000      188000
c5      188000      188000
```

### [`Fiddle Demo 2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23d8a/6)

Comment: Problem with this query is that if you want to output only `city` and `totalSalary` you need to remove `e1.maxSalary` from the `select` statement and if you do that it throws an error of `unknown column e1.maxSalary in having clause`, so you need to declare `e1`again

Comment: @babu you can use sub-select over your final query ans selected only needed columns [see demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23d8a/7)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid it will throw error without e1.maxSalary field in the select statement. Please erase e1.maxSalary in Fiddle and see the reault

Comment: @babu for having clause its necessary the column you are using in having should be present in select list if you don't want `e1.maxSalary` in end result then i have provided another demo of sub-select thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think i found an answer.
The reason it is not giving the correct answer is the same reason if we try

```
SELECT name, MAX(salary) FROM employee
```

will not work cause it only outputs the first record of name , though it gives max salary
so we need to compare salary field with the max salary

```
SELECT name, salary FROM employee
WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employee)
```

So the actual query of my question would be

```
SELECT city, totalSalary
FROM( SELECT city, SUM(salary) AS totalSalary FROM employee GROUP BY city  ) AS tempTable
WHERE totalSalary =
(SELECT MAX(totalSalary) FROM ( SELECT city, SUM(salary) AS totalSalary FROM employee GROUP BY city  ) AS tempTable)
```

we need to declare tempTable again, or it will say tempTable doesn't exist.

Comment: your query simulates the HAVING clause by a WHERE clause. Maybe the usage of a HAVING clause would  more directly express it.